# Accounting for the Earth's curvature when using GroundOverlays

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I have a .tif file (a satellite image) and a corresponding .tfw file. I've successfully converted the extracted the coordinates (lat/lng) from the world file and I've converted the .tif file into a .png file using Photoshop. Using that, I've added a ground overlay into Google Maps. The upper left corner of the image looks good but when I move away from that corner, the discrepancy between my satellite image and that of Google's keeps getting bigger. I know this has something to do with the Earth being round and not flat. Is what I'm doing even possible or is there a step or two that I'm missing here?

Comment: Google maps uses a mercator projection. It sounds like you are accounting for that.

Answer (score 0):

This is just something to verify but it could throw the overlay off. From: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/groundoverlay

> Note: When the image is added to the map it will be converted to an image with sides that are powers of two. You can avoid this conversion by using an original image with dimensions that are powers of two — for example, 128x512 or 1024x1024.

Posting your overlay code may help as well.